# Get data from "remote" json to current json ionic 3

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, ionic3

I have an Object like this

```
 mapsToSync = {to:this.token,fils:[{src:"",md5:""}]};
```

and here i want to populate fils with a json from assets

```
 this.http.get('../assets/fills.json').map(res => res.json()).subscribe(data => {
            this.mapsToSync.fils.push(data.fills);
        });
```

And fills.json is

```
{
    "fills":[
        {"src":"","md5":""},
        {"src":"","md5":""},
        {"src":"","md5":""}
    ]
}
```

My problem is this. My object is now something like this:

```
{
to:this.token,
fils:[{src:"",md5:""},[{src:"",md5:""},{src:"",md5:""},{src:"",md5:""}]]
};
```

I want

```
  {
    to:this.token,
    fils:[{src:"",md5:""},{src:"",md5:""},{src:"",md5:""},{src:"",md5:""}]
    };
```

If a try to manipulate data I get back, for example data.length -> length of undefined. So data is not ready. I have to use async awaint function?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since your `mapsToSync.fils` and `data.fills` have the same array structure, You can merge them using concat functionality directly too.

```
 this.http.get('../assets/fills.json').map(res => res.json()).subscribe(data => {

this.mapsToSync.fils=this.mapsToSync.fils.concat(data.fills);


        });
```

This way your existing data will persist with the new data

Comment: But in the declaration I have  mapsToSync = {to:this.token,fils:[{src:"",md5:""}]};. So If i declare like this: mapsToSync = {to:this.token,fils:[{src:"somePath",md5:"dfgfhdh4234456"}]};. I will lose the info about its src and fills. Some way to push?

Comment: There is an error . You have to assign it : this.mapsToSync.fils = this.mapsToSync.fils.concat(data.fills);

Comment: Yeah, I just missed that have updated the answer now

Comment: Thank you. This is the answer